# Inequality connecting inf and liminf

Tags: analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Suppose $f(x,y)$ is a continuous, nonnegative-valued and bounded function on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Is the following correct?
$$
\inf_{x,y} f(x,y)\le \liminf_{y\to\infty}\inf_{x}f(x,y) 
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\inf_{x,y} f(x,y)\leq \inf_{x}f(x,y)$$
and thus
$$\inf_{x,y}f(x,y)=\liminf_{y\to\infty }\inf_{x,y}f(x,y)\leq \liminf_{y\to\infty }\inf_x f(x,y)$$

what conclude the proof.

Comment: Using the same symbol in an infimum and (on the other side of the inequality) as a true symbol seems most unwise in a teaching context. Likewise, in the second displayed line, $\liminf\limits_{y\to\infty}\inf\limits_{x,y}f(x,y)$ is exactly the kind of "niceties" which could throw off beginners.